# Multibyte characters for "Report this ad" string are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, international-sites, translations, character-escaping

On the top page of [Stack Overflow for Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) (スタック・オーバーフロー), I found a string below an ad is shown as a kind of [character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references):

> [image: screenshot]

It shows `&#x3053;&#x306E;&#x5E83;&#x544A;&#x3092;&#x5831;&#x544A;`, which can be decoded to "この広告を報告", a translated string of "Report this ad". See https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13323.

I also confirmed a related behavior happens on [Stack Overflow for Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) and [Stack Overflow for Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/).

SOpt:

> [image: screenshot]

SOru:

> [image: screenshot]

These strings should be shown in decoded forms.

My environment: Windows 11, Google Chrome 106.0.5249.119

The same meta post on SOja: [「この広告を報告」がエンコードされた状態で表示されている](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3798/19110)

Comment: But the link itself is working, i.e. you can report ads?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard yes, it's still working properly, [the dialog to report it appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBOKn.png) (with partially translated :( ).

Comment: As of November 4th, there is no more "report ad" link as [this comment by staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383517/the-page-on-the-site-ru-stackoverflow-com-is-going-crazy#comment1279298_383517) says. (They removed it as the bugs it's causing are fatal.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue should now be fixed. (Technically, I think it got fixed about a month ago, but it seems this post never got responded to – sorry about that!)