# The page on the site ru.stackoverflow.com is going crazy!

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, advertising

After visiting any question this happens:

[image: "Report this ad" button is not properly localized, and body text of question is stretched out vertically over multiple line (one character per line).]

I tried to open the site on different browsers (Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge) - it did not help. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Kinda looks like whatever font your browsers are using can't handle Russian characters, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I do repro this. The Ad on that page is the culprit. That might be a security issue. The bug is in the element `js-report-ad-button-container`

Comment: No repro Chrome, windows 10.

Comment: just tried vpn - same result!

Comment: I had to disable u-block to get a repro.

Comment: @Spevacus don't think so - the top of the page doesn't have layout issues and it has Cyrillic characters. Also, Cyrillic characters don't usually cause such layout problems. Whatever it is, it's unlikely to being Cyrillic.

Comment: I see the same ad but I'm not reproducing that behavior

Comment: If this is specific to that site, shouldn't it be reported in the per site meta?

Comment: @RandomPerson Not needed. It's definitely about the software that powers the entire network.

Comment: @RandomPerson is it really a problem to report it here if it's unknown whether it's specific to that site? And even if it *is* specific - it seems it's a problem with the *generic functionality* of the SE network. Something related to ads and how they are served. Which seems very network-related.

Comment: Potentially related issue, for the issue with the "Report this ad" link: [Multibyte characters for "Report this ad" string are broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383153/335251)

Comment: The relevant team will investigate this further sometime next week. In the meantime, we've temporarily disabled the "Report this ad" link on Stack Overflow in Russian for now to prevent this issue. Let us know if you continue to experience this problem in the meantime.

Comment: Please don't accept answers until the bug is fixed. Having answer accepted when the bug is still there is both misleading, and reduce chances of the bug getting actually fixed.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard No, it doesn't reduce any chances. The status tags determine the status of a report, not its accept status.

Comment: @Sonic I disagree. CM might see accepted answer and think "Oh, great, it's resolved! Let's mark it as completed". That's actually expected behavior.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard unmarked 'accept answers', my bad

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can repro this for some pages when specific Ads are run (I disabled [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin) in Chrome for a moment):

[image]

The Ad on that page is the culprit. The bug is caused by content in the element `js-report-ad-button-container` and that seems to be running external JavaScript, hopefully from Google.

One page where I had the issue was: [Отправитель на кириллице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463965) but we should be looking for specific Ads I think, not for specific Q/A pages.

The Ad in the image is:
`<a id="aw0" target="_blank" href="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjsuPCLM3jXwPa5PWvdl0SiaUdqB_4SzV0hzi0bFPIMsyYWxaPlRWx1KdB1dTaEHq0rJl2inkBFaMmUQMHQUTF11BrztdmAQogRrnnoUQN3Flqm0IoZQf18tfm6neNmXXnmDxrUI1i7nrgu9w57qc8LEttQprDiqtcV5rvpG2PyfpoIA6u_TmgtPmD7IKws3pS5n9Wb78MRDTLT-n3evKfnxjpo-xs4Iqh2lOHAQ6YDOq0iIxE7t6PMS1VAR17HqmFCa6KDEN-0usXtwBg_La4W7sFUNNqboQaDjCG1JfNwj4xmI1gjJP74G9dVV_caL98_Ddw3xGm82zP50ucV8GGhs-hnmArXcnUxjJIGOx920&amp;sig=Cg0ArKJSzIwCKj5ncHaD&amp;fbs_aeid=[gw_fbsaeid]&amp;adurl=https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7122&amp;nm=5&amp;nx=175&amp;ny=-199&amp;mb=2" onfocus="ss('aw0')" onmousedown="st('aw0')" onmouseover="ss('aw0')" onclick="ha('aw0')"><img src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/4081962686600106887" border="0" width="300" height="250" alt="" class="img_ad"></a>`

Comment: Are you able to report the specific add?

Comment: @Luuklag what makes a google ad specific? I now copied the whole markup.

Comment: Good point, that wasn't easily visible (on mobile).

Comment: @rene so thank you, now everything looks good now!

Comment: @Lenny rene didn't fix anything, the bug isn't fixed. They simply removed the bad element until they will investigate, but the bug is not fixed.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard hey! Stop spoiling my fame!

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard  I just figured that out. ><

Answer (score 10):

This has been fixed, thank you for reporting this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Meta! Love your bio. :)